# Community Page Page Variation

Tags: community, page-variation

This might be a silly question, but how do you reference a page variation? For example, I have a community page, and it has a page variation based on market.

- MyNewPage_US
- MyNewPage_UK

Is there a way to reference them via URL? For Example,

- https://mydev-company.cs60.force.com/service/s/MyNewPage_UK
- https://mydev-company.cs60.force.com/service/s/MyNewPage_US

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Page variations live at different URLs. Variations for a given page all live at the same URL (the path is configured at the page level). But the system chooses the variation to display based on the audience criteria applied to the visitor.

For a geography-based audience, you could potentially test by visiting the page over a VPN connection that goes through the UK or the US.